# Why is C++ much faster than Python here?

Tags: python, c++, performance

I was practicing on leetcode question #5. What really puzzles me is the huge runtime difference between C++ (~20ms) and Python (~1000ms) here.

I understand that Python is an interpreted language so in general it is slower than C++. But here C++ being 50 times faster than Python is beyond my understanding. Both programs use the same algorithm so it's not that. Is it due to how strings are implemented in C++ and Python?

C++

```
class Solution {
public:
    string longestPalindrome(string s) {
        if(s.size() == 0) return "";
        int length = 1, index = 0, subOddLength = 1, subEvenLength = 1, subLength = 1;
        for(int i = 1; i < s.size(); ++i){
            subOddLength = palindromeLength(s, i, i); 
            subEvenLength = palindromeLength(s, i - 1, i);
            subLength = max(subOddLength, subEvenLength);
            if(subLength > length){
                length = subLength;
                index = i - subLength / 2;
            }
        }
        return s.substr(index, length);
    }
private:
    int palindromeLength(const string &s, int l, int r){
        int n = s.size();
        while(l >= 0 & r < n){
            if(s[l] != s[r]) break;
            l--; r++;
        }
        l++; r--;
        return r - l + 1;
    }
};
```

Python

```
class Solution:
    def longestPalindrome(self, s: str) -> str:
        
        def palindrome_length(l, r):
            while l >= 0 and r < len(s):
                if s[l] != s[r]: break;
                l -= 1; r += 1
            l += 1; r -= 1
            return r - l + 1
        
        length, index = 1, 0
        for i in range(1, len(s)):
            odd_len = palindrome_length(i, i)
            even_len = palindrome_length(i - 1, i)
            sub_len = max(odd_len, even_len)
            if sub_len > length:
                length, index = sub_len, i - sub_len // 2
        return s[index : index + length]
```

Comment: how did you measure? How did you compile the code?

Comment: Please share a [mcve] so we can try it ourselves. It is hard to speculate on performance, you usually need to use tools to analyze it and subtle changes can have big impacts. Without knowing exactly what you measured, trying to guess about performance characteristics of your code is likely to be inaccurate.

Comment: Comparing C++ to Python is not really a fair comparison. Python uses a VM, C++ compiles to optimized, native machine code. Why not try in Cython where it's at least compiled? Don't forget Python needs to load *Python* before it runs even a single line of code. The C++ program is a tiny executable that does *only* what you want.

Comment: if you run your python code again 2-3 times in leetcode compilers, you will find there is execution time difference for each execution having same code and input

Comment: For a "fairer" comparison, time how long it takes to run a zero-line Python program, then subtract that from the results. Also do more than 1 iteration. You want to benchmark for at least 60+ seconds to have any meaningful data.

Comment: Your question is not specific enough. We can not compare every control structure and command for performance and explain it.You will have to profile the runtime of the application yourself and show us the values of a single piece of code in order to make the question answerable.

Comment: Please include the main function that performs the timing, so we can try it out.

Comment: "Same algoritm" - But the primitive operations aren't the same. For instance, since integers are immutable in python, we will see `+=` creating objects all over the place for large integers. That incurs cost. Transliterating code != same behavior.